# pn junction in series i-v curve

Tags: series, pn-junction

If i have \$p^+n -pn^+\$ junctions in series how should the i-v curve look? my guess is that because they have the same orientation in the meaning of forward/reverse bias so it's should look like regular pn junction, am i right?

Comment: Is the connection between the n layer and p layer in the semiconductor, or is there a wire between the p+n junction and the pn+ junction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with the difference that the voltage at which the series connected diodes start conducting will be roughly doubled.